# Line Breaks and Wrapping

Tags: resharper

In my Resharper options the `Right Margin` was set to a low value which made my code wrapped into something like this

```
new Employee {
    Name = "John",
    Id =
        (int)
        EmployeeIDs.John,
    Cost = 8,
    Level = 0,
    Type =
        EmployeeType.Type1
}
```

However, now as i set the `Right Margin` `"@ Options -> Code Editing -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Line Breaks and Wrapping"` to a high value of `300` and reformatted the code i didn't get Resharper to fix the cropped lines for me as i expected the result to be something like this

```
new Employee {
    Name = "John",
    Id = (int)EmployeeIDs.John,
    Cost = 8,
    Level = 0,
    Type = EmployeeType.Type1
}
```

How could i get the above desired result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please uncheck following checkbox:

ReSharper | Options | Code Editing | C# | Formatting Style | Line Breaks and Wrapping | Preserve Existing Formatting | Keep existing line breaks

Then start code cleanup once again.